# How to pass a dictionary through pd.series in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My code output was displaying the series but after restarting the Kernel in python it says 'dict' object is not callable. Sometimes when i write a piece of code it gives error but after restarting the kernel it resolves the issue. I want to know that should i change my IDE? Because Jupyter has been giving me a lot of trouble lately or maybe my code syntax is not right.

```
area_dict = {'California': 423967, 'Texas': 695662, 'New York': 141297,
                 'Florida': 170312, 'Illinois': 149995}
    area = pd.Series(area_dict) 
    area
    
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-17-81271a07bba5> in <module>
          1 area_dict = {'California': 423967, 'Texas': 695662, 'New York': 141297,
          2              'Florida': 170312, 'Illinois': 149995}
    ----> 3 area = pd.Series(area_dict)
          4 area
    
    TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: it is a problem with juypter notebook, in native python IDE it is not giving error

Comment: You probably have something like `pd.Series = area_dict` in one of the previous cells before this one, and that causes the error. It "redirects" `pd.Series` to be a dictionary object.

Comment: @TamilSelvan The error isn't Jupyter-specific.

Comment: @Neither thanks. I found out my mistake.